# Transparent equivalent of given color

Tags: r, colors, alpha-transparency

I've had this a few times, so here goes: I'm making some plots which hold curves with estimates of a parameter given a tuning parameter.

Typically, I also have SDs for each estimated value, so I could show error bars around each of them.

However, I don't like error bars, and would prefer some smoothed version of it. This is in itself no problem (ie I know how to do this). However, my plot contains several of these similar curves, each one in its own color. So I would like to add the 'smoothed errorregion' to each curve in a color that matches the color of the curve itself. Of course, I would like to do this somewhat transparently, so I can still see the other curves through the 'error region'.

So, my question is: given a color (specified by either a number, a name or an rgb value --- note the first two pose an extra problem, but this is occurring rather often, as the basic plotting functions take these as valid color values), how can I find find the matching color that has the same rgb but a different (given) alpha level (transparency). I would like a function like:

```
makeTransparent<-function(someColor, alpha=100)
{
  newColor<-someColor + alpha #I wish
  return(newColor)
}
```

This should work for things like:

```
makeTransparent(2)
makeTransparent("red")
makeTransparent(rgb(0,0,1))
```

**Edit** I hate it when I miss something obvious, but @themel pointed me to it (thx again). Here's a full solution (note: works vectorized, so you can pass more than one color; only one alpha is supported at this time though):

```
#note: always pass alpha on the 0-255 scale
makeTransparent<-function(someColor, alpha=100)
{
  newColor<-col2rgb(someColor)
  apply(newColor, 2, function(curcoldata){rgb(red=curcoldata[1], green=curcoldata[2],
    blue=curcoldata[3],alpha=alpha, maxColorValue=255)})
}
```

Comment: There's `alpha` in `scales` too, maybe they're related.  The one is scales has a really nice interface.  It's quite flexible in its input.  I think any expression of the form `plot(data, col=colors)` can be replaced with `plot(data, col=alpha(colors,0.5))` to get 50% transparency.  This works even if `colors` is simply a vector of integers that select a color from the standard palette.

Comment: somewhat related (according to Google anyway) and which I found very useful: https://gist.github.com/mages/5339689/raw/576263b8f0550125b61f4ddba127f5aa00fa2014/add.alpha.R

Comment: I see this is old, but the package YaRrr seems to be able to do this (e.g., https://bookdown.org/ndphillips/YaRrr/low-level-plotting-functions.html, https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/yarrr/versions/0.1.5/topics/transparent)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Have you had a look at `?rgb`?

> Usage:
>
> rgb(red, green, blue, alpha, names = NULL, maxColorValue = 1)
>
> An alpha transparency value can also be specified (as an opacity,
>   so ‘0’ means fully transparent and ‘max’ means opaque).  If
>   alpha’ is not specified, an opaque colour is generated.

The `alpha` parameter is for specifying transparency.  `col2rgb` splits R colors specified in other ways into RGB so you can feed them to `rgb`.

Comment: `col2rgb` was the thing I was missing - must have read over it :-( Also I wouldn't have expected this to work on colors already in rgb format. I'll edit my own question to include a full answer based on yours.

Comment: Didn't know about `col2rgb`, that is really useful!

Comment: In my case it was also necessary to transpose col2rgb() return value and pass maxColorValue argument for normalization: rgb(t(col2rgb(c("red", "green"))), alpha=100, maxColorValue = 255)

Comment: `alpha = 0.0` means "fully transparent", `alpha = 1.0` (or 255 if scaled in the 8-bit integer range) means "fully opaque". I keep forgetting this, let's record for the sake of those who are similarly challenged :-)

Answer (score 104):

There is a function `adjustcolor` in `grDevices` package coming with the base installation of R, that works like this in your case:

```
    adjustcolor( "red", alpha.f = 0.2)
```

Comment: This is very useful since accepts HEX formated and already created colors as input!

Comment: Way more useful as the accepted answer. With this function `alpha` can be specified as a floating-point value which is what people usually use.

Answer (score 8):

I think is more common to specify `alpha` in `[0,1]`. This function do that, plus accept several colors as arguments:

```
makeTransparent = function(..., alpha=0.5) {

  if(alpha<0 | alpha>1) stop("alpha must be between 0 and 1")

  alpha = floor(255*alpha)  
  newColor = col2rgb(col=unlist(list(...)), alpha=FALSE)

  .makeTransparent = function(col, alpha) {
    rgb(red=col[1], green=col[2], blue=col[3], alpha=alpha, maxColorValue=255)
  }

  newColor = apply(newColor, 2, .makeTransparent, alpha=alpha)

  return(newColor)

}
```

And, to test:

```
makeTransparent(2, 4)
[1] "#FF00007F" "#0000FF7F"
makeTransparent("red", "blue")
[1] "#FF00007F" "#0000FF7F"
makeTransparent(rgb(1,0,0), rgb(0,0,1))
[1] "#FF00007F" "#0000FF7F"

makeTransparent("red", "blue", alpha=0.8)
[1] "#FF0000CC" "#0000FFCC"
```

Answer (score 6):

Converting [valuable comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047668/transparent-equivalent-of-given-color#comment29539619_8047668) to answer:

Use [`alpha` from package `scales`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/scales/topics/alpha) - first argument is colour, second alpha (in 0-1 range).

Or write function overt it:

```
makeTransparent <- function(someColor, alpha=100) scales::alpha(someColor, alpha/100)
```

Answer (score 6):

Easily convert hexidecimal colour codes like so

```
adjustcolor("#F8766D", alpha.f = 0.2)
[1] "#F8766D33"
```

To confirm it worked:

```
library(scales)
show_col(c("#F8766D", "#F8766D33"))
```

[image]